# AngularJS how to enable color printing css while using ng-style?

Tags: css, angularjs, ng-style, print-css

I have an app that generates some data in a table, and each cell has a specific combination of background color and text color, given by its properties.

the code for that is a simple:

```
ng-style='{"background-color": lt.backgroundColor, "color": lt.textColor}'>
```

now I need to implement a print view, so only some elements get printed, but my main issue is that I need the colors to be printed, they are important, and for that usually I always added a `!important` to the css rule and it would get printed.

But this time, I have ng-style that is giving colors,
so how on earth can I add `!important` inside a ng-style?

I tried: `lt.backgroundColor+""+"!important"` but it's not working,

hell, even `ng-style='{"background-color": "#000 !important"....}`
is working, only if I remove the !important like:

```
ng-style='{"background-color": "#000"....}
```

leaving only the hex code, it shows in the print view correctly,

any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to interpolate your attribute:

```
ng-style='{"background-color": {{lt.backgroundColor}}+' !important', "color": {{lt.textColor}} }'>
```

Comment: sadly that is not working :( I even tried to use " " instead of ' ' around !important, but won't work, and I tried to swap external '' with "", and use internally '', but nothing

Comment: The point is not about simple or double quote, that's the same! The important thing is to interpolate your variables such as `lt.backgroundcolor`

Comment: ok, but then what's the issue? the double curly brackets get a different color from the outside one (xcode), so maybe I can't use them like that? (typescript)